# Geospatial Indexing DB with High Rate Update

Tags: android, database, geospatial, nosql

I want to build an mobile app, with geospatial indexing for high rate query and high rate updating. What kind of database I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously used mongodb with fairly good results. my calls take around 4ms for a 270,000 entry database of coordinates. here is a link to some examples:
[MongoDB 2dsphere tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/)

I can't say if this is the fastest or best method around but it is fairly easy to implement and has many well thought of tools for optimization and querying.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.